# jscript: visibility / document.readyState not working

Tags: stylesheet, visibility, hidden, visible, jscript

I want to hide the content until the page is fully loaded,
but i cant finde the problem why it dosent work.

the alert shows up, but not the content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#content{
    visibility:hidden;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    checkLoad();
    function checkLoad(){
        if (document.readyState === "complete"){
            document.getElementById("content").style.visiblity = 'visible';
            alert(document.getElementById("content").style.visiblity);
        } else {
            setTimeout('checkLoad();', 1000)
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id='tc1'>Content Text</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code:

```
document.getElementById("content").style.visiblity = 'visible';
```

should be :

```
document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

(note the missing **i** in visibility)